# List of listing space before title

Tags: spacing, listings

I know I can control the space of my listing titles with:

```
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{35pt} % TOC: Table of Contents
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{35pt} % LOF: Listing of Figures
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{35pt} % LOT: Listing of Tables
```

But whats the equivalent for `List of Listing`?

```
\setlength{\cftbeforeloltitleskip}{35pt} % LOL: List of Listings
```

Does not work...

So now my titles are not on the same height. How to fix?

Comment: If you look into the [source code](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.dtx), you'll see that it uses `\tableofcontents`. I'm reading from my browser, but it's nearly 85% down the page (keyword search for "listoflistings").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after your folks' help I figured it must be a package that screwed up my list of listings behavior/styling.

After some debugging I found the package: the package `float` screws it up!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\title{List of listings problem}
\author{Gerjan}
\date{June 2016}

\usepackage[english]{babel}    
% \usepackage{float} % Including this package influences the behavior of LOL!
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0em} 
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0em}
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0em}

\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{10em} % Should affect toc AND lol

% toc and lol styling
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\normalfont\large}

% list of figures styling
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\normalfont\Huge}

% list of tables styling
\renewcommand\cftlottitlefont{\normalfont\Huge}

% title of toc
\renewcommand\contentsname{Contents}

% title of lof
\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}

% title of lot
\renewcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}

% title of lol
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Listings}

% Table of contents (toc)
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\tableofcontents

% List of figures (lof)
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\listoffigures

% List of tables (lot)
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\listoftables

% List of listings (lol)
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\lstlistoflistings

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}

\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Try to include or not include the `float` package and see the difference.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Solved here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316830/float-package-screws-up-list-of-listing-format-style/316843#316843

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution. Use `\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{<dimen>}` because
`\lstlistoflistings` use `\tableofcontents`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{listings}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{5cm}
\begin{document}
A
\lstlistoflistings
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={bla bla},label=list]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;

Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, this is weird, this doesn't work. Setting `\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{10pt}` only affects the toc, and not the lol.
Something is messing with my lol config?

Comment: @GerjanOnline for your convenience try with 5cm rather than 10pt.

Comment: if it doesn't help please add a minimal example.

Comment: I've created a MWE and then it works, I don't know who is screwing with my lol titles :(