# Float package screws up list of listing format/style

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

Can anyone explain the following behavior:

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\title{List of listings problem}
\author{Gerjan}
\date{June 2016}


%\usepackage{babel} % Use dutch, british or english
\usepackage[english]{babel}


% \usepackage{float} % Including this package influences the behavior of LOL!
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0em} 
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0em}
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0em}

\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{10em} % Should affect toc AND lol

% toc and lol styling
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\normalfont\large}

% list of figures styling
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\normalfont\Huge}

% list of tables styling
\renewcommand\cftlottitlefont{\normalfont\Huge}

% title of toc
\renewcommand\contentsname{Contents}

% title of lof
\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}

% title of lot
\renewcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}

% title of lol
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Listings}

% Table of contents (toc)
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\tableofcontents

% List of figures (lof)
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\listoffigures

% List of tables (lot)
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\listoftables

% List of listings (lol)
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\lstlistoflistings

% Below is only needed when the float package is used
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}

\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

When I include (remove the comment) the `float` package, the following happens:

1. The title style (font, spacing etc) of the List of Listings can not
   be modified (normally, LOL's title style is the same as the TOC)
2. List of Listing is not listed in the ToC (you need to do
   it manually)

Comment: Are you sure that `tocloft` will change list of ... floats that are under the control of the `float` package? I don't think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually,it's the interaction of `float` and `listings` to prevent the correct (or desired behaviour)

The following code is from `listings`

```
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistoflistings{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistlistingname
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lol}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\@ifundefined{float@listhead}{}{%
  \renewcommand*{\lstlistoflistings}{%
    \begingroup
      \@ifundefined{@restonecoltrue}{}{%
        \if@twocolumn
          \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
        \else
          \@restonecolfalse
        \fi
      }%
      \float@listhead{\lstlistlistingname}%
      \parskip\z@\parindent\z@\parfillskip \z@ \@plus 1fil%
      \@starttoc{lol}%
      \@ifundefined{@restonecoltrue}{}{%
        \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
      }%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
```

As soon as `float@listhead` is defined (which is the case if `float` is loaded), `listings` redefines `\lstlistoflistings`.

In order to prevent this, use `float` here after `listings` and after `tocbibind` etc!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\title{List of listings problem}
\author{Gerjan}
\date{June 2016}


%\usepackage{babel} % Use dutch, british or english
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{tocbibind}


\usepackage{listings}


\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{float} % Including this package influences the behavior of LOL!


\AtBeginDocument{%

% toc and lol styling
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\normalfont\large}

% list of figures styling
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\normalfont\Huge}

% list of tables styling
\renewcommand\cftlottitlefont{\normalfont\Huge}

% title of toc
\renewcommand\contentsname{Contents}

% title of lof
\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}

% title of lot
\renewcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}

% title of lol
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Listings}

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0em} 
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0em}
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0em}

\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{10em} % Should affect toc AND lol
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}

% Table of contents (toc)
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

% List of figures (lof)
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures

% List of tables (lot)
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables

% List of listings (lol)
\cleardoublepage
\lstlistoflistings

% Below is only needed when the float package is used
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Foo}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Foo figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,caption={Foo listing}]
int main(void)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```